# How do I use multiple sort criteria in cfdirectory list?

Tags: coldfusion, cfdirectory

I know that cfdirectory has a tag for sort, and if I have sort="DateLastModified DESC", it works. If I have sort="Name DESC", it works. But if I have sort="DateLastModified DESC, Name DESC", it doesn't do the second sort. I've tried both using a comma and a pipe to separate, neither works.

```
<cfdirectory 
    action="List" 
    directory="#docRoot#" 
    type="file" 
    Recurse="Yes" 
    sort="DateLastModified DESC, Name DESC" 
    name="FileQ" > 
<cfdump var="#FileQ#">
```

Comment: According to this piece of Adobe documentation, https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdirectory.html, what you describe should give the desired results.  Please edit your question by adding the complete `<cfdirectory>` tag, whatever output code you have, and a few rows of data showing the undesired sort.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the result set that you get back is a query object, which means you can probably use it to do a query of queries operation and perform a secondary sort. See: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html

Comment: @Redtopia is correct, but the Q of Q should not be necessary.

Comment: Is the DateLastModified  really identic? Maybe some milliseconds are swallowed but differ

Comment: The code looks fine.  Could you show a couple of improperly sorted rows of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recopied the files with correct dates, so the issue resolved itself. However, I think Bernhard Dobler may have hit the nail on the head, it is most likely that the DateLastModified was not completely identical (off by milliseconds)